# jQuery and Extension [Submit not working]

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, mozilla

Good day.
I want to add jQuery in my FireFox extension 
I add file in .xul and use this code:

main.xul:

```
<overlay id="sample"
   xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://mozillatest/content/jquery.js" />
   <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://mozillatest/content/main.js" />
</overlay>
```

main.js file:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 $whatever = jQuery.noConflict();

 if (window.$whatever) {
  alert('1 check - OK 1!');

 $whatever('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  alert('submited');
 });
});
```

I see alert "1 check - OK 1!" 
But when i navigate to some sites and press submit, i cant see alert "submited".
I write extension in Chrome and it is work without problem!
What i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

You're loading jquery into browser.xul, which is not what you actually want. You want it in the context of pages.

I suggest you have a look at the [add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/developers/builder) instead of writing a plain XUL extension because not only will this be easier for your general use case, the SDK is also a lot more like a chrome extension. Have a look at the [`page-mod` SDK module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html).

If you still want to use plain XUL, you'd have to do the heavy lifting, that the SDK would do for you, yourself, i.e. [`intercepting page loads`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Intercepting_Page_Loads) and then using DOM methods (or jQuery, but not the regular "style") to interact with sites. But before that you'd need to wrap your head around `browser.xul` and xul windows in general, overlays, `<tabbrowser>` and how it relates to `browser.xul` and much more.

Comment: Thanks you for you answer! But i can't understand you fully....can you give me some exemples? Or, if it is not difficult for you, can you help to change my extension to work with chrome..)

Comment: Examples? The whole problem is far too broad for that. I'd have to essentially create a whole add-on for you, and this is not a code writing service. I feel I gave you the necessary pointer and information you need to get started on an actual add-on.

Comment: Another question: Can i make hook submit without jQuery?